# How to start multiple Ruby scripts simultaneously from bash script

Tags: ruby, bash, batch-file

How can I launch several different ruby scripts in order from a bash script?

I've managed to achieve it on my Windows machine with a batch file but I'm struggling to figure out how to do it with bash.

Here's the contents of my batch file for reference:

```
start "1" cmd /k ruby replicaServer.rb
start "2" cmd /k ruby FileServer.rb
start "3" cmd /k ruby fileServer2.rb
start "4" cmd /k ruby directoryServer.rb
start "5" cmd /k ruby LockServer.rb
start "6" cmd /k ruby ClientProxy.rb
start "7" cmd /k ruby client.rb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby replicaServer.rb &
/usr/local/bin/ruby FileServer.rb &
/usr/local/bin/ruby fileServer2.rb &
/usr/local/bin/ruby directoryServer.rb &
/usr/local/bin/ruby LockServer.rb &
/usr/local/bin/ruby ClientProxy.rb &
/usr/local/bin/ruby client.rb &
```

Adjust the path to wherever you actually keep the `ruby` executable, lose the ampersands if you want things to run sequentially rather than in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Is there a way for each script to be opened in individual terminal windows rather than all in one window? I should have mentioned that in my original question, apologies.

Comment: @ConorB To the best of my knowledge, that would depend entirely on what OS and what windowing system you're using.  Launch your favorite terminal app as shown above, passing each copy a single one of the ruby invocations as an execution argument.